# Add !important to hidden property in React jsx inline style

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styles, jsx

How can I add !important to hidden property in React jsx inline style?

I'm trying to hide the scroll bar in an Ag Grid table component because by default Ag Grid shows the scroll bar.

I alredy tried:

```
                  ref={(node) => {
                    if (node) {
                      node.style.setProperty('overflow-x', 'hidden', 'important');
                    }
                  }}
```

but it's not working

Comment: where is your jsx?

Answer (score 0):

I recreated what you do and it worked fine. I don't see an error right now. Maybe your overflow-x attribute is set by a library/framework after you have set it in the ref-function.

```js
function App() {
  return <h1 style = {
    {
      width: '10px',
      overflowX: 'visible'
    }
  }
  ref = {
    node => {
      if (node) {
        node.style.setProperty('overflow-x', 'hidden', 'important')
      }
    }
  } > Hi!This some overflow text < /h1>;
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @johannchopin, could you figure it out?